# Fat-Free Framework & Abide AJAX form submission not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, fat-free-framework

I'm using Foundation 5.5.3 and Abide form validation for my site registration.  So my Javascript looks like this:

```
$('form#register').on('valid.fndtn.abide', function() {
  var data = {
        'email'     : $('#email').val(),
        'username'  : $('#username').val(),
        'password'  : $('#password').val()
      };

  $.ajax({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'user',
    data: $('#email, #username, #password').serialize(),
    beforeSend: function() {
      console.log(data);
    }
  });
});
```

I'm skipping adding the HTML here because I can see from the `console.log` that the data showing there in the `data` object.  I've tried disabling `async` and adding `headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}` and neither worked.

Then in F3, I have the following:

```
$f3->map('/user', 'User');

class User {
  private $email;
  private $username;
  private $password;

  function get() { }

  function post($f3) {
    global $handler; // This is a PHPConsole handler instance for debugging

    $email = $f3->get('PARAMS.email');
    $username = $f3->get('PARAMS.username');
    $password = $f3->get('PARAMS.password');

    $handler->debug($email, 'email:');
    $handler->debug($username, 'username:');
    $handler->debug($password, 'password:');
  }

  function put() {

  }

  function delete() {

  }
}
```

The debug outputs of `$email`, `$username`, and `password` are always `null` from PHPConsole.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing it wrong

```
$email = $f3->get('PARAMS.email');
$username = $f3->get('PARAMS.username');
$password = $f3->get('PARAMS.password');
```

Should be

```
$email = $f3->get('POST.email');
$username = $f3->get('POST.username');
$password = $f3->get('POST.password');
```

F3 stores Get data in `$f3->get('GET');`, post data in `$f3->get('POST.email');`
etc

Comment: Correct!  Thanks for the answer!